# Farseer Physics non-XNA on separated thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, farseer

I'm developing a game in C# with Farseer Physics without XNA. I put `world.Step(float dt)` in a separated thread in order to keep the form alive (in fact, a while loop would block every other operation). Well, the ball, a dynamic body, runs faster or slower depending on CPU frequency I think. I thought about `Thread.Sleep()` with a delay time calculated by reading the CPU frequency and mutiplying it by something, but I'm pretty sure I'm wrong. I'm a little noob. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` is very much not an accurate way to time things. You want to use something like:

```
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
```

Which you can then use to drive a timed update loop like this:

```
// Run enough updates to catch up to the current time
private void Idle()
{
    double time = timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    accumulatedTime += (time - lastTime);
    lastTime = time;

    const double frameTime = 1.0/60.0; // 60 frames per second
    while(accumulatedTime > frameTime)
    {
        world.Step((float)frameTime);
        accumulatedTime -= frameTime;
    }
}
```

You can then call the above `Idle` method followed by a short `Sleep` in a loop.

Or you could just call it from an event handler for `Application.Idle` - either directly on the UI thread, or by signalling your other thread.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to learn the code.
is frameTime the time I want to wait?
What does `Update` do?

Comment: Sorry, that was code I copied out of an existing project - I had meant to change it to better match your question, before I posted, but then forgot. I'll fix it now :) Basically `frameTime` is the time in seconds between frames. `Update` is whatever method updates your game state (like `Step`).

Comment: Wohoo, I'll try it out soon, I hope. Thanks a lot! Ah, just one thing left: I assume lastTime must be initializated to zero ;)

Comment: @LivingSilver94 Yes. Although watch out, in that case, that you don't create and start the `Stopwatch` before (time consuming) loading of resources, etc, and then find that the update loop tries to update many times to catch up. To be extra-safe, you might wish to modify the code so that it cancels any `accumulatedTime` time over some threshold.